# How can I use IF ELSE in WHERE clause on the basis of a string variable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have an SP. It returns some number of rows. Here is the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetClients]
```

`(
    @orderBy varchar(50),
    @startAge int,
    @endAge int,
    @sex char,
    @staffId nvarchar(1024), 
    @statusId nvarchar(1024), 
    @ethnicityId nvarchar(1024), 
    @treatmentProviderId nvarchar(1024)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;`

```
IF(@orderBy = 'Consumer Name')
BEGIN
    SELECT c.Id, dbo.GetClientFullName(c.FirstName, c.MiddleInit, c.LastName) AS ClientName, 
    c.DateOfBirth, dbo.GetAge(c.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) AS Age, c.Sex, 
    dbo.GetClientStatus(c.Id, @statusId) AS Status, ca.Address, co.Phone, 
    dbo.GetEthnicity(c.Id, @ethnicityId) AS Ethnicity, dbo.GetDevelopmentalDisabilities(c.Id) AS Disabilities, 
    dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) AS Staff, dbo.GetClientContacts(c.Id) AS Contact, 
    dbo.GetClientInsuranceProviders(c.Id) AS HealthProvider, 
    dbo.GetClientTreatmentProviders(c.Id, @treatmentProviderId) AS TreatmentProvider
    FROM Client c  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(        
        SELECT ca.ParentEntityId, ca.Address
        FROM ContactAddress ca
        INNER JOIN EntityName en ON en.Id = ca.EntityNameId AND en.Name = 'Client' 
        INNER JOIN GeneralLookup gl ON ca.glAddressTypeId = gl.Id AND gl.LookupItem = 'Primary'    
    ) ca ON c.Id = ca.ParentEntityId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(        
        SELECT co.ParentEntityId, co.ContactData Phone
        FROM ContactOther co
        INNER JOIN EntityName en ON en.Id = co.EntityNameId AND en.Name = 'Client' 
        INNER JOIN GeneralLookup gl ON co.glContactTypeId = gl.Id AND gl.LookupItem = 'Home'    
    ) co ON c.Id = co.ParentEntityId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GeneralStatus gs on gs.Id = c.StatusId
    where gs.Name <> 'Deleted' 
    and (dbo.GetAge(c.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) BETWEEN @startAge and @endAge)
    and ((@sex = 'M' and c.sex = 'M') or (@sex = 'F' and c.Sex = 'F') or (@sex = '' and (c.Sex in ('M', 'F', ''))))
    and dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null
    and dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null
    and dbo.GetClientStatus(c.Id, @statusId) is not null 
    and dbo.GetEthnicity(c.Id, @ethnicityId) is not null 
    and dbo.GetClientTreatmentProviders(c.Id, @treatmentProviderId) is not null
    ORDER BY ClientName
END
END
```

The UDFs(User defined functions) are dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) and other. They return some rows which are having null as well. That's why I'm using last 5 statements in where clause so that only non null values can be collected. Everything is working fine but the problem is, I want this check of non null only when these variables are NOT empty string:

```
@staffId nvarchar(1024), 
@statusId nvarchar(1024), 
@ethnicityId nvarchar(1024), 
@treatmentProviderId nvarchar(1024)
```

How can I resolve this issue?
I want something like this:

`If @staffId <> '' then dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 AND  ((@staffId = "") OR (dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null))
```

Comment: I used this: `AND Case @staffId WHEN '' THEN 1=1 ELSE dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null END` It is giving the error `Incorrect syntax near '='`

Comment: Sorry - Answer modified - it's been a while since I wrote SQL lol

Comment: This solution is also working perfectly. Can you explain this a bit?

Comment: Quite simply it will include the row if either of the 2 clauses return true. So either where @staffid = "", or if StaffId !="" then it will try the second clause and call the function checking for a non-null return.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do logical comparisons within a CASE statement. You have to produce a value from a case expression, and the type of each possible value produced must be the same, or convertible:

```
CASE @staffId
    WHEN "" THEN 1
    ELSE
       CASE
           WHEN dbo.GetClientStaffContacts(c.Id, @staffId) is not null THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END
END = 1
```

Would be a condition you could put in your `WHERE` clause

---

There are two forms of CASE expression possible:

- Simple CASE (when you're trying to find a WHEN clause that is equal to the provided value after the keyword CASE) - this is what the outer CASE expression is doing (trying to find a WHEN clause that matches the `@StaffId` value).
- Searched CASE (when you're trying to match a WHEN clause based on arbitrary predicates) - this is what the inner CASE expression is doing (testing whether the return of the function is not null)

You can't determine NULL/non-NULL status using a Simple CASE expression, since NULL is not equal to NULL (nor is it not equal).

Comment: Hey, that's working perfectly. Thanks a lot. Can you explain this a bit more that what the Second CASE is doing here?

Comment: I marked answer the first one because it is more simple. I wished to mark yours one but it would be more helpful for upcoming users in search of this question .. Hope you won't mind :)